# How to specify list of files in HTML form?

Tags: html, html-input

When you use a `<input type="file">` in your application you get the file select dialog box with all files as default.

Is there a way to specify file types for that? Is it possible for example to select ".txt" files only?

Comment: yes you will have to use javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is really simple. All you do is add an `accept` attribute that defines what file extensions you'd like to allow.

```
<input type="file" accept="image/gif,image/jpeg">
```

That input would allow only gif and jpegs, but you can allow any comma separated list.

See: 
http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/forms/file.html#filter
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_accept.asp

edit: sure, you can do this with javascript too, by checking the filetype after selecting a file, but wouldn't you rather check *before* the user selects a file?

Comment: OP asked for a method for txt files not images

Answer (score 1):

on your validation you can check the file type or you can use the on change event to determine the file type.

```
<input name='upload' id='file' type='file' />
```

Javascript part

```
var file = document.getElementById('file');

if (file.value.test(/(\.txt)|(\.jpg)/gi)) { // case insensitive
  // then validate
}
```

in this case only txt or jpg will be accepted. but of course you will have to revalidate on the server side because javascript can easily be bypassed

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with the `accept` attribute.

Any ol' garbage can be posted regardless of what you put in the HTML form so make sure to validate that the correct file type has been posted server-side.